# Term for when you stop code execution early on with an if?

Tags: design-patterns

What's the term for when you stop code flow early on with some sort of if statement and a return value?

E.g.:

```
bool myFunc(){
    if(userNotAllowed){ // <- What is this called?
        return false; // I've heard it given a name before.
    }
    //do lots of stuff
    //etc etc
    return true;
}
```

It's a sort of simple design pattern of sorts...
An example would be look-before-you-leap or it's "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission".
But I don't think it has a silly name like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a Guard Clause. See

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause

And

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)

Comment: For some reason I forget this term regularly and have to look back at your answer. I think I need to drill it into by brain by repeating it to myself...

Comment: Guard Clause is Santa Claus' older brother. He protects Santa when he has to deliver presents to some of the seedier neighborhoods.

There, that's so weird there's no way you'll forget it :-)

Comment: This is his [t-shirt](https://res.cloudinary.com/teepublic/image/private/s--TWGMhdUN--/t_Resized%20Artwork/c_crop,x_10,y_10/c_fit,w_470/c_crop,g_north_west,h_626,w_470,x_0,y_0/g_north_west,u_upload:v1462829021:production:blanks:ypmyd1fntg5klzifbc7n,x_-395,y_-325/b_rgb:eeeeee/c_limit,f_jpg,h_630,q_90,w_630/v1511380716/production/designs/2089284_0.jpg):